# Tkinter Canvas "Go-To" Function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Python, and I'm working with the tkinter canvas. I currently use

```
pos = canvas.coords(object)
speed = 5 #could be any number though
destpos = canvas.coords(destination)

xdist = destpos[2]-pos[2] 
ydist = destpos[3]-pos[3]

#finds hypotenuse of an imaginary right triangle

fraction = speed/math.sqrt(xdist**2+ydist**2)

#puts the values into ratio so the object knows how far x and y they need to go

x = xdist * fraction
y = ydist * fraction

#canvas.move() function so the object moves

canvas.move(self.id, x, y)
```

However, I'd like a simple already added method of moving an object to another destination at a given speed.

I need to use this code dozens of times in an application I'm working on, and I'd prefer using a simpler method compared to a function.

In summary, what I want is a simple method of completing the same task that is a bit easier to understand. (The method is a bit buggy and I can't ever figure out why)

Comment: so why not use a function? All you need to do is pass the canvas object to the function and then move the object.

Comment: I could totally do that I'm just looking to see if there's another way of doing it

Comment: Using a generic function that can accept say the canvas object and the new coordinates should be simple enough to use and would be the correct method of processing an object move when you have many locations in your code that need to do this.

Comment: I get that but I'm asking if another way exists
Perhaps I worded my question wrong?

Comment: There only two concepts I feel you should use here is either a function or a class method. Both are a kind of function. A class method is a function in a class that is accessible to other methods within the class or from outside of the class. However if you are still wanting to know something else then you will need to provided a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the code you have provided is not testable.